# Fsharp.data "Illegal characters in path"

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm just getting started in F# and was exploring FSharp.Data. I'm trying to use a web service from www.ncdc.noaa.gov. The first problem is ncdc wants a token in the request. I attempted to work around that with the following:

```
let apiUrl = "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&locationid=ZIP:28801&startdate=2010-04-01&enddate=2010-04-01"
    let aRequestString = 
            Http.RequestString(
                apiUrl, 
                httpMethod="GET", 
                headers = [ "token", "mytoken"])
    let sf = WeatherData.Load(aRequestString)
```

This seems to work - fiddler says I get a result that looks good to me and JSONLint, but I get "Illegal characters in path." from the provider.

The stack trace shows:

```
System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.UriResolver.Resolve(Uri uri)
FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncRead(FSharpOption`1 _tp, UriResolver uriResolver, String formatName, String encodingStr, Uri uri)
FSharp.Data.Runtime.IO.asyncReadTextAtRuntime@238.Invoke(Uri uri)
```

Comment: Do you need to escape the characters or some such?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It seems I'm getting valid JSON back from the service. The Load method throws, what would I escape? why and where?

Comment: Not sure.  Illegal characters just suggests unescaped characters somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Load` method takes a URL or a file path and it loads data from there. If you're downloading the data on your own, you need to use the `Parse` method instead.

```
let apiUrl = "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=...."
let aRequestString = 
        Http.RequestString(
            apiUrl, 
            httpMethod="GET", 
            headers = [ "token", "mytoken"])
let sf = WeatherData.Parse(aRequestString) 
//                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: Solved the issue for me too.  Tomáš Petříček - the Jon Skeet of F# :)